# Question about solving infinite loop from integrating data passed from useLocation to useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

If I have user data being passed in location.state from a Form component with useNavigate to another Table component with useLocation, how can I then append that data to the end of a table of users returned from Form component?(Note: I am being redirected from Form component to table component after submitting my form using react-router-dom. Form component and Table component are called by App.js. I am trying to pass data between components without the prop system. In Table component, I have a [users, setUsers] = useState([]). Users is populated with data I fetched from an api. I want to add the user data I got from Form component to table of users I fetched and is displaying).  I get infinite loop if I write:

setUsers([...users, location.state]);

My thoughts are to use useMemo or useEffect to solve the infinite loop. But I can't figure out how to use it (or if that is the right approach). Sorry, I am new to react. I wanted to test  implementing this type of routing/passing data. I know there are other ways to do routing/passing data but I am looking for a solution & explanation for this specific routing/passing data. If someone can provide it, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../style.css";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function List() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function onClickHandler(e) {
    navigate("/Form");
  }

  let location = useLocation();
  console.log("location.state: ", location.state);
  if (location.state !== null) {
    setUsers([...users, location.state]);
    location.state = null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Website</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>{user.website}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Add Contact</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: *Where* are you using `setUsers([...users, location.state]);`? If you are unconditionally enqueuing state updates this can certainly cause render looping. Can you [edit] the post to share a more complete and relevant [mcve]?

Comment: I edited the post with Table.js. I am just not sure where to go from here to stop the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the code is basically unconditionally enqueuing a state update as an unintentional side-effect, i.e. directly from the body of the React function component.

The logic should be moved into a `useEffect` hook so it is run as an *intentional* side-effect. Instead of trying to mutate the `location.state` object the code should issue a redirect to the current route sans the passed state, i.e. remove the data that was just added to local state.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const { state, ...rest } = location; // rest has pathname, search, etc
  if (state) {
    setUsers(users => [...users, state]);
    navigate(rest, { state: null, replace: true });
  }
}, [location]);
```